# ¿Cómo funciona ORDER BY en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Mi duda es la siguiente, en la siguiente tabla utilice `ORDER BY` para ordenar la tabla por semanas.
El problema es que en el campo de ganadores ordena bien los números de la semana nones bien (1,3) y los números de semana par (2,4) los invierte. ¿por que pasa esto?

[image: Imagen de referencia]

```
SELECT semana, local.nom_equipo, goles_loc, visitante.nom_equipo, goles_vis, ganador FROM partidos 
JOIN equipos local ON partidos.num_eqpo_loc = local.num_eqpo 
JOIN equipos visitante ON partidos.num_eqpo_vis = visitante.num_eqpo ORDER BY semana;
```

Answer (score 2):

La sentencia `ORDER BY` a grandes rasgos lo que hace es tomar una columna completa de valores y ordernarlas de forma ascendente o descendente dependiendo de como le hayas dicho tu que lo hace, por defecto los va a ordernar de forma ascedente.

Puedes leer un poco mas de esta parte teorica en [The SQL ORDER BY Keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

La sintaxis de esta sentencia es

```
... ORDER BY [table.]column [ASC|DESC]
```

Donde los valores dentro de corchetes `[]` pueden ser opcionales, sin embargo en consultas con `JOIN` se puede poner para indicar de forma correcta a que columna nos referimos.

En cuanto a tu pregunta puede ser la referenciación de los elementos amigo, ya que al estar con un JOIN puede ser que haya otra semana registrada en alguna otra de las tablas.

Lo que yo haria es algo como lo siguiente

```
SELECT partidos.semana AS Semana, CONCAT(local.nom_equipo," vs ", visitante.nom_equipo) AS Partido, partidos.goles_loc AS "Goles de local", goles_vis AS "Goles de visitante", ganador AS Ganador 
FROM partidos 
JOIN equipos local ON partidos.num_eqpo_loc = local.num_eqpo 
JOIN equipos visitante ON partidos.num_eqpo_vis = visitante.num_eqpo 
ORDER BY semana ASC;
```

Con esto deberias tener una salida como la siguiente

```
Semana        Partido                Goles de local        Goles de visitante    Ganador 
1             AMERICA vs CRUZ AZUL      2                      0                 AMERICA
```

Y estarian ordenados en orden acendente de 1-N

Espero haber respondido tu pregunta.